# nuget package with sourcecode without SymbolSource.org

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to publish a nuget package with source code and pdb files for debugging without using SymbolSource.org

We have our own internal nuget source and have proprietary core projects that we add to nearly every solution, what I would like to do is as part of the build process create a nuget package and push to our internal nuget source.  The only examples I see of creating a package with pdb file and source are by creating a symbol package and pushing to SymbolSource.org

Comment: Just to clarify, we are also working on a version of SymbolSource that you will be able to install yourself behing a corporate firewall. However, I cannot announce any release date yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymbolSource.org provides private source repositories http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/29 which require authentication. If your company policy doesn't support that, there is an existing NuGet bug to add better support for what you're describing.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1543

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to update this with [the following blog post from symbolsource](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2012-03-13/Releasing_the_community_edition_of_SymbolSource):

> For some time now we have been speaking about a community edition of
>   SymbolSource. Starting from today it is available on NuGet the same
>   way that NuGet.Server is, and serves a similar purpose: to internally
>   host symbols and sources in a debugger-friendly way.